# ExpandableListView with no children throws indexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, kotlin, android-listview, expandablelistview

I have an `ExpandableListView` where some groups have children and some not, what I need to do is to expand only the groups that have children.

Part of the `body` array elements is empty and because of that, I'm getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

```
    class ExpandableInnerCartAdapter(
        var context: Context,
        var expandableListView: ExpandableListView,
        var header: MutableList<Cart>,
        val isTerminadoFragment:Boolean
    ) : BaseExpandableListAdapter() {
    
        val map = SparseBooleanArray()
        var body: List<List<String>> = listOf()
    
        override fun getGroup(groupPosition: Int): Cart {
           return header[groupPosition]
        }
    
        override fun isChildSelectable(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int): Boolean {
           return true
        }
    
        override fun hasStableIds(): Boolean {
            return false
        }
    
        fun getCart(): MutableList<Cart> = header
        fun getCheckedArray():SparseBooleanArray = map
    
        override fun getGroupView(
            groupPosition: Int,
            isExpanded: Boolean,
            convertView: View?,
            parent: ViewGroup?
        ): View {
    
            var convertView = convertView
            if(convertView == null){
                val inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_group,null)
            }
            val item = header[groupPosition]
            body = listOf(item.optionList)
            expandableListView.expandGroup(groupPosition)
            expandableListView.setGroupIndicator(null)
            convertView.item_name.text = item.productName
           
            return convertView
    
        }
    
        override fun getChildrenCount(groupPosition: Int): Int {
            return body[groupPosition].size
        }
    
        override fun getChild(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int): Any {
            return body[groupPosition][childPosition]
        }
    
        override fun getGroupId(groupPosition: Int): Long {
            return groupPosition.toLong()
        }
    
        override fun getChildView(
            groupPosition: Int,
            childPosition: Int,
            isLastChild: Boolean,
            convertView: View?,
            parent: ViewGroup?
        ): View {
            var convertView = convertView
            if(convertView == null){
                val inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_child,null)
            }
            if(getChildrenCount(groupPosition) > 0){
                val title = convertView?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_title)
                title?.text = "Opción ${childPosition+1} -> ${getChild(groupPosition,childPosition)}"
            }
    
            return convertView!!
        }
    
        override fun getChildId(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int): Long {
            return childPosition.toLong()
        }
    
        override fun getGroupCount(): Int {
            return header.size
        }
    }
```

The error seems like it's happening when no group has children and try to do

```
    expandableListView.expandGroup(groupPosition)
```

I have tried to fix the issue with an if statement:

```
    if(body.isNotEmpty()){
        expandableListView.expandGroup(groupPosition)
    }
```

but this solution does not work.

How do I avoid groups that do not have children?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you use Kotlin you have a lot of useful extension functions at your disposal. One of them is `filter` for which you can specify condition, of course.

The solution would be to filter out empty arrays from the list you set as the new `body` value:

```
    body = listOf(item.optionList).filter { it.isNotEmpty() }
```

Filter function definition can be seen [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter.html).